# Do gods keep their +1/+1 counters if they stop being creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do counters added to a god with [Gleam of Battle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleam%20of%20Battle) disappear when the god stops being a creature?

Scenario: [Purphoros, God of the Forge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Purphoros%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Forge) is a creature (due to devotion reaching the required amount) and Gleam of Battle is also on the battlefield. Then Purphoros attacks and gets a +1/+1 counter for attacking. If my devotion to red then drops below 5 and Purphoros is no longer a creature, would the +1/+1 counters stay on him or will he reset to his original power/toughness level?

My thinking is when he becomes an enchantment he loses it due to the fact that he is no longer a creature and that his power and toughness are technically not there and so he gets remade into being a creature only when devotion is high enough.

Answer (score 6):

They absolutely stay. According to the comprehensive rules, emphasis mine:

> 205.1a Some effects set an object's card type. In such cases, the new card type(s) replaces any existing card types. **Counters**, effects, and damage marked on the object remain with it, **even if they are meaningless to the new card type**.

Comment: Impressively short and to the point. There are 245 occurences of the word *Counter* in the comp rules, and section 121 is literally titled *121. Counters*, and yet you somehow found this in section 205.

Answer (score 5):

Counters are not removed from a permanent even when they stop being relevant to it.

Take the example of [Raging Ravine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaging%20Ravine%5d) : it says

> 2RG: Until end of turn, Raging Ravine becomes a 3/3 red and green
>   Elemental creature with "Whenever this creature attacks, put a +1/+1
>   counter on it." It's still a land.

On gatherer we can see the ruling :

> Any +1/+1 counters put on Raging Ravine remain on it even after it
>   stops being a creature. They'll have no effect until it becomes a
>   creature again.

Related : [Can non-creature permanents have +1/+1 counters?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/16662/can-lands-have-1-1-counters/)

Comment: Better yet, Llanowar Reborn prove that +1/+1 counters can exist on non-creatures without relying on rulings.